StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found. Error while iterating through hrefs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.common import exceptions
ser_obj = Service("C:/Users/sunda/Downloads/Drivers/Chrome.exe")

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="C:/Users/sunda/Downloads/Drivers/msedgedriver")
product_model_list = []
driver.get("https://time-mark.com/")
# Extract the value of the href attribute
a_tags = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

for a_tag in a_tags:

    product_name_url = a_tag.get_attribute('href')
    if "product-category" in product_name_url:
        print(product_name_url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.get(product_name_url)
        a_tag_product_name = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        for product in a_tag_product_name:
            product_model = product.get_attribute('href')
            # try:
            if "3-phase-monitors" in product_model and "page" not in product_model and 
               "shop" in product_model:
                product_model_list.append(product_model)
                print("product name = ",product_model)

print(product_model_list)

i have this code above and I want to get all the href values and append to a list. When I try to run the code above, I get the following error. I am very new to webscraping. please help me fix this issue. I have also added the URL I am trying to get this info from. Any work around is also appreciated. I want the the list called "product_model_list" with all the "product_model" appended to it.
File "C:\Users\sunda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found
(Session info: MicrosoftEdge=122.0.2365.92)

Inside the for loop you're calling driver.get(product_name_url) which loads a new page, so the remaining items in a_tags now refer to elements that are no longer on the current page, which means they are stale.

@JohnGordon so what would be the work around for this if i want to loop through and hit one https:// api at a time and retrieve the information in that particular page?

Then a_tags should be a list of plain text urls, not a list of elements.
